# Нет доступа к value

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему это не работает, не могу получить `value`?

```
var doc = document,
    inputT = doc.querySelector('#inputText').value;
    el.innerHTML = inputT;
```

Только если сделать так:

```
 el.innerHTML = inputT.value;
```

---

```js
var doc = document,
  inputT = doc.querySelector('#inputText'),
  addElFirst = doc.querySelector('#dayBtn'),
  divP = doc.querySelector('#container');

function addElemToFirst() {     //Поместить новый элемент первым.
  var el = doc.createElement('p');  //Создаем новый элемент p.
  el.innerHTML = inputT.value;

  divP.parentNode.insertBefore(el, divP.parentNode.firstChild);
}

addElFirst.addEventListener('click', addElemToFirst, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="text" id="inputText" value="">
<button id='dayBtn'>День</button>
<div><div id="container"></div></div>
```

Comment: в чем конкретно проблема? что за элемент _inputText_? почему решили, что не можете получить _value_? Куда нужно вставить строку _el.innerHTML = inputT.value;_, предыдущий код заработал как надо?

Comment: Я дополнил код и оформил его так что бы можно было его запустить. Проверьте так ли работает код как должен

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с кодом в том, что значение поля `value` - Это строка и получив ее один раз, она не будет меняться самостоятельно каждый раз как меняется значение в поле ввода.

Так как до нажатия на кнопку значение поля может меняться, единственный способ получить текущее значение поля ввода во время клика - взять его непосредственно из инпута в обработчике.

Comment: Как вариант - использовать `MutationObserver` и обновлять переменную при изменении.

Comment: @Other, да, может быть, не видно какой-то особой выгоды от этого

Comment: Быть может... Затраты на наблюдателя могут быть больше, чем на геттер элемента. Но как экзотика - почему нет?

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML — позволяет получить HTML-содержимое элемента в виде строки.
Свойство innerHTML есть только у узлов-элементов.

А value — значение поля. Value есть у INPUT, SELECT или TEXTAREA.

**upd** Понял вопрос.

Прикладываю код. У меня всё работает.

```js
var doc = document, 
    el = doc.querySelector('#el'),
    inputT = doc.querySelector('#inputText').value;
    el.innerHTML = inputT;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputText" value="test">
<div id="el"></div>
```

Comment: Все правильно, я пытаюсь получить значение у инпута. затем это значение вставить в созданный мною новый элемент.

Comment: И оно не работает?

Comment: Все работает)) Вы наверное не совсем поняли о чем я хотел спросить)

Comment: @fara Добавил пример кода — у меня всё работает. Что то может не так написал?

Comment: У меня все также как и у вас!! НО. может быть так как я создаю динамически новый элемент, поэтому у меня не работает ? Прилагаю выше свой код.

Comment: Какой именно элемент. Можете чуть больше кода показать?

Answer (score -1):

1. Код document.querySelector('#inputText'); даст тебе элемент DOM. На вопрос, "что является содержимым элемента?" можно дать *три* ответа:

   1. *Содержимое* элемента – *это разметка*, которая внутри него. innerHTML, outerHTML  применяется для этого.
   2. Как *весь текст внутри* него. Используется textContent  или innerText.  Свойство textContent поддерживается всеми текущими броузерами, кроме IE. В IE вместо него можно использовать свойство innerText. Но эти свойства немного отличаются.
   3. *Содержимое* элемента - это все *узлы*, которые в нем внутри есть.
      Это насчет того, *как понимать* содержимое.
2. Теперь насчет свойства value. свойства в объект дерева ДОМ переходят из атрибутов (атрибутов соответствующего объекту-узлу элемента) + есть чисто джаваскриптовые свойства, например, length. методы у объекта-узла - все чисто джаваскриптовые. свойство value есть далеко не у всех объектов DOM. обычно это свойство содержит то, что, например, ввел человек в поле инпута или текстареи (*руками ввел*), или что руками выбрал в селекте.